# Is there a way to have a 'cleaner' top of nodeJS app, lot of modules requires

Tags: node.js, npm

I'am trying to find if there is a way to have a cleaner 'top' of node app.
I have a lot of modules requirement, maybe there is a way to include them from another js file like modules.js or something ?

```
var express = require('express');
var vision = require('node-cloud-vision-api');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
var toArray = require('json-to-array');
var sizeof = require('object-sizeof');
var _ = require('underscore');
var request = require('request');
var unique = require('array-unique');
var async = require("async");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var chrono = require('chrono-node');
var fs = require('fs');
var path    = require('path');
var pdf2img = require('pdf2img');
var Knwl = require("knwl.js");
var knwlInstance = new Knwl('english');
var remove = require('array-remove');
var Fuse = require('fuse.js');
Array.prototype.remove = require("array-remove-by-value");
var fuzzysearch = require('fuzzysearch');
var promise = require('promise');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var Occurrences = require('occurences');
var session = require('express-session');
var multer = require('multer'),
```

Comment: Do you use all those modules in a single file? If so, you may want to consider modularizing your application.

Comment: If you're importing that many modules into one file, it's probably a sign you should be splitting that file into multiple modules.

Answer (score 0):

@Joe Clay is right.

But if you want to keep your app's top cleaner do:

make a modules.js file. First Import and then Export the modules in this file.

Where ever you want to use some module extract them using destructuring i.e.

var {module_name,... } = require(path_to/modules.js);